# I have a question about "Back" of the screen transition of SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

```
"A> B> A> B> A ..."
```

When repeating the operation of switching from `screen A` to `screen B` and returning to `screen A` again, we believe that if the following code is used, the load will continue to accumulate because the old screen information is retained.

However, the return code included in `"NavigationLink"` does not reload the previous screen, so the following code is currently used:

#### Question:

What if I want to always reload the screen when recalling the old screen?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var Flag : Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {self.Flag.toggle()}){
                    Text("OpenA")
                    NavigationLink(destination: A(),isActive: $Flag) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true).navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}


struct A: View {
    @State private var Flag : Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Group{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {self.Flag.toggle()}){
                    Text("A > B")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: B(),isActive: $Flag) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true).navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct B: View {
    @State private var Flag : Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Group{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {self.Flag.toggle()}){
                    Text("B > A")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: A(),isActive: $Flag) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true).navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. > the return code included in "NavigationLink"

NavigationLink is struct, so it nothing like returning value exists, except the NavigationLink itself

On the other site

```
NavigationLink(destination: A(),isActive: $Flag) {
    EmptyView()
}
```

one of its constructor's parameter is binding to Bool value

```
@State private var Flag : Bool = false
```

If user click on navigation link, this value change to `true`, once the linked View is dismissed by user, it changed to `false` again. That means, ContentView is informed about and the ContentView has to recalculate its body property (in other words, if there is something different in its body, the value will reflect that.

I don't see nothing is changed there! What do you expect?

Comment: @notane what is your expectation? how it should work (what is your requirements)?

Comment: There was a problem with my question.

For example, suppose you execute a process on screen A and go to screen B.
Here, when you return to screen A using the button displayed on the NavigationBar, the executed process is the same as before the transition because it has not been reloaded.

Use NavigationLink to move from screen B to screen A to reload this.

However, in this case, the load increases because the screen remains for each execution.

Looking for a solution for this.

Comment: @notane what i can see OpenA  Press the link, new View is A>B. Press the link and next View is B>A Press the link .. A>B next B>A ... and so on. What is your expectation? the code now works as written.

Comment: @notane the destination in navlink is A() (NEW INSTANCE OF STRUCT A), next destination is B() (NEW INSTANCE OF STRUCT B) ... and so on.

Comment: Is my perception wrong?
When a new instance is created, the existing Instagram will remain.
We believe that if you hold down this button indefinitely, a new instance will always be created and the operation will become unstable. (Exceeds memory limit)
Since this process only assumes returning to the previous screen, we are looking for a way to transition to the previous screen by reloading the screen without consuming memory.

Comment: That is true, navigation stack ( NavigationView ) will soon or later crash ...  remove all modifiers .navigationXXXXX from your code and test the functionality. back button is there to "go to previous screen". Try to follow basic Apple tutorial first, if SwiftUI is new concept for you.

Comment: Thank you.
One question is, can't I kill the already displayed View instance?

Comment: @notane SwfiftUI will do that (it will kill anything nor anybody :-)) by removing the View (which is value, not reference) from navigation stack (it is part of internal state of NavigationView)